# NgRX - Store Modelling

Tags: ngrx, state-machine

Im creating an interface to send notifications.
The form will have the following fields:

- title
- message
- users <-- Autocomplete

Im not sure how to model the state for this behaviour.

I already have an store:

```
export interface NotificationState extends EntityState<NotificationModle> {
  loading: boolean;
  loaded: boolean;
  total: number;
  current_page: number;
  per_page: number;
}
```

Should I add a new users properties to my state or create a new one?

Answer (score 0):

What you have for `NotificationModel` is correct.

User is a separate entity and should have its own `EntityState`.